# Unable to process base64 from iphone in php

Tags: php, ios, iphone, base64

I,m using base_64 methods for sending files from android/iphone devices to php server.

The php code i'm using to convert base64 as file is:

```
file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($data));
```

The file from **android working fine**, and file from **iphone is in corrupted state**.

When we compare the base64 encoded string for a particular file from both devices, it returns different outputs, and the string from iphone is much smaller than it from android.

Is that the issue ?, if yes how to solve it ?

Following are the base64 string from both:

Base 64 from android:

```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=
```

Base 64 from iphone:

```
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
```

Comment: android's probably generating base64 formatted to be used in a MIME document, e.g. an email. You'd have to strip out the linebreaks to turn it into a single-line string.

Comment: @MarcB: for android its working fine, what about base64 in iphone.. any way for using same method as in android.

Comment: then you've marked your code samples backwards. the "android" version has line breaks, the ios version doesn't.

Comment: thanks, but regardless of the line breaks, both the strings seems to be entirely differnet....

Comment: b64 is b64. ignoring the line breaks, you should get identical b64 data from both systems, which means that the data you're encoding is different on the two systems. `ivBORw0K` is a PNG file header, which probably means the pngs have different structures internally. might be the exact same image, but different metadata.

Comment: Show us the code in which you prepare and send the base64 request in iOS. Show us how you're doing it in Android.

Comment: The Base64 is different because it is not of the same data. The one with link breaks has 4257 characters (ignoring line break characters) and the other 777 characters. So the encoding is from different sources. They both seem to be PNG image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decoded both Base64 strings and saved the results as .png files, below are the results:

Note 1: A quick online decode of the initial bytes reviewed that the data were PNG files.
Note 2: I use the terms larger and smaller because it seems the Base64 strings are mislabeled.

The  decoded image from "Base 64 from iPhone" is the image: [image] with a file size of 528 bytes.

The decoded image from "Base 64 from android" is the image: [image] with a file size of 3191 bytes.

So, they are both valid Base64 representations of the same image but from different files. The larger file has more EXIF information in it.

Note 3: You should strip all non image information from image files used in apps to save space.

EXIF from smaller file:
---- ExifTool ----
ExifTool Version Number:
9.70
---- System ----
File Name:
a.png
Directory:
/Users/dan/Desktop
File Size:
582 bytes
File Modification Date/Time:
2014:10:21 11:23:17-04:00
File Access Date/Time:
2014:10:21 11:31:55-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time:
2014:10:21 11:23:28-04:00
File Permissions:
rw-r--r--
---- File ----
File Type:
PNG
MIME Type:
image/png
---- PNG ----
Image Width:
10
Image Height:
13
Bit Depth:
8
Color Type:
RGB with Alpha
Compression:
Deflate/Inflate
Filter:
Adaptive
Interlace:
Noninterlaced
---- Composite ----
Image Size:
10x13

EXIF information from larger file:
---- ExifTool ----
ExifTool Version Number:
9.70
---- System ----
File Name:
b.png
Directory:
/Users/dan/Desktop
File Size:
3.1 kB
File Modification Date/Time:
2014:10:21 11:26:22-04:00
File Access Date/Time:
2014:10:21 11:31:55-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time:
2014:10:21 11:26:22-04:00
File Permissions:
rw-r--r--
---- File ----
File Type:
PNG
MIME Type:
image/png
---- PNG ----
Image Width:
10
Image Height:
13
Bit Depth:
8
Color Type:
RGB with Alpha
Compression:
Deflate/Inflate
Filter:
Adaptive
Interlace:
Noninterlaced
Profile Name:
Photoshop ICC profile
White Point X:
0.31269
White Point Y:
0.32899
Red X:
0.63999
Red Y:
0.33001
Green X:
0.3
Green Y:
0.6
Blue X:
0.15
Blue Y:
0.05999
---- PNG-pHYs ----
Pixels Per Unit X:
2835
Pixels Per Unit Y:
2835
Pixel Units:
meters
---- ICC-header ----
Profile CMM Type:
Lino
Profile Version:
2.1.0
Profile Class:
Display Device Profile
Color Space Data:
RGB
Profile Connection Space:
XYZ
Profile Date Time:
1998:02:09 06:49:00
Profile File Signature:
acsp
Primary Platform:
Microsoft Corporation
CMM Flags:
Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer:
IEC
Device Model:
sRGB
Device Attributes:
Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent:
Media-Relative Colorimetric
Connection Space Illuminant:
0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator:
HP
Profile ID:
0
---- ICC_Profile ----
Profile Copyright:
Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company
Profile Description:
sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Media White Point:
0.95045 1 1.08905
Media Black Point:
0 0 0
Red Matrix Column:
0.43607 0.22249 0.01392
Green Matrix Column:
0.38515 0.71687 0.09708
Blue Matrix Column:
0.14307 0.06061 0.7141
Device Mfg Desc:
IEC http://www.iec.ch
Device Model Desc:
IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB
Viewing Cond Desc:
Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1
Luminance:
76.03647 80 87.12462
Technology:
Cathode Ray Tube Display
Red Tone Reproduction Curve:
(Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve:
(Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve:
(Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
---- ICC-view ----
Viewing Cond Illuminant:
19.6445 20.3718 16.8089
Viewing Cond Surround:
3.92889 4.07439 3.36179
Viewing Cond Illuminant Type:
D50
---- ICC-meas ----
Measurement Observer:
CIE 1931
Measurement Backing:
0 0 0
Measurement Geometry:
Unknown
Measurement Flare:
0.999%
Measurement Illuminant:
D65
---- Composite ----
Image Size:
10x13

Comment: which method you used to decode the files (in php or not)

Comment: in php me used file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($data)); for both - but android is working and ios not...

Comment: Perhaps php can not handle the EXIF information. Save the files without the EXIF information. The bottom line is that different image files are being Base64 encoded. Perhaps Android removed the EXIF information.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Base64 encoding. Notice I took the posted Base64 strings, converted to data and obtained the images. The images are identical, the EXIF data is not. I copied the Base64 strings from SO, saved in a text file. Read the file into an `NSData` with `dataWithContentsOfFile:`, de-encoded with `initWithBase64EncodedData:options:` and saved as .png file with `writeToFile:atomically:`. Then uploaded the files into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS i have the same problem but the issue of different bit size files is other thing.

For the base64encode i replace the "+" from the enconde string.

Like this:

```
self.stringImageEnconded = [self.encodedImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```